# canvas - get pixels on a line

Tags: javascript, canvas

I need a function that accept 5 arguments (ctx, startX, startY, endX, endY). It should return pixels on a canvas that lay on the line, that starts on (startX, startY) and ends on (endX, endY). How can I implement it?

Comment: This is too broad, please be more specific about what you have tried and what the problem is with your solution. SO are not here to write  the solution for you. Check the SO guidelines before posting.

Comment: There is infinite points in a line segment, which one you need to find?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Brensenham line algorithm. It will get each pixel without needing to check if you already have that pixel which many other line methods would need.

```
    function getPixelsOnLine(ctx, startX, startY, endX, endY){
        const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
        const data = imageData.data;
        const pixelCols = [];
        const getPixel = (x,y) => {
            if(x < 0 || x >= imageData.width || y < 0 || y >= imageData.height ){
                return "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
            }
            const ind = (x + y * imageData.width) * 4;
            return `rgba(${data[ind++]},${data[ind++]},${data[ind++]},${data[ind++]/255})`;
        }

        var x = Math.floor(startX);
        var y = Math.floor(startY);
        const xx = Math.floor(endX);
        const yy = Math.floor(endY);
        const dx = Math.abs(xx - x); 
        const sx = x < xx ? 1 : -1;
        const dy = -Math.abs(yy - y);
        const sy = y < yy ? 1 : -1;
        var err = dx + dy;
        var e2;
        var end = false;
        while (!end) {
            pixelCols.push(getpixel(x,y));
            if ((x === xx && y === yy)) {
                end = true;
            } else {
                e2 = 2 * err;
                if (e2 >= dy) {
                    err += dy;
                    x += sx;
                }
                if (e2 <= dx) {
                    err += dx;
                    y += sy;
                }
            }
        }
        return pixelCols;
    }
```

Function returns array of pixel as CSS color values `rgba(red,green,blue,alpha)` on line from start to end.